# How can I tell the distance from a turtlebot to an obstacle?

Tags: ros, kinect, turtlebot, avoidance, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am working on obstacle avoidance using turtlebot with kinect sensor. I need help with determining how far an obstacle is from the turtlebot. I want to use this process to incorporate it into a multiple robots where they will move and avoid obstacles.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238431/how-can-i-tell-the-distance-from-a-turtlebot-to-an-obstacle?/) by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2016-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I see three main ways do to what you want:

1. convert the depth image provided by kinect into a laser scan with [depthimage_to_laserscan](http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan) and get the smallest range
2. process directly the depth image, for example looking for the lowest intensity pixel. For best performance, use a computer vision library as [OpenCV](http://wiki.ros.org/vision_opencv)
3. process directly the pointcloud that kinect can also provide, possibly using [PCL](http://pointclouds.org)

An example for way 3 is the [turtlebot_follower](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot_follower): doesn't look for the closest obstacle, but for any significatively big obstacle in front of the robot (and follows it). But probably use PCL is a bit overkilling for simple obstacle avoidance....

An example for way 2 is....  the same! I have seem @Tully Foote has rewritten turtlebot_follower in kinetic to use depth image procesed with OpenCV (not 100% sure) instead of PCL

That said, your question is rather vague... can you provide some more details about your plans?

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2016-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2016-06-29**:
We are working on a multiple turtlebots for formation change. Our plan is to be able to change formation when there is a barrier so multiple robots can pass through a gate.

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2016-07-08**:
is there a code in c++ out there I can use for reference? We are planning to do an obstacle avoidance where we will expand into multi turtlebots.

**Comment by [Vinh K](https://answers.ros.org/users/23017/vinh-k/) on 2016-07-18**:
based on method 1. [depthimage_to_laserscan](https://github.com/ros-perception/depthimage_to_laserscan/blob/indigo-devel/src/DepthImageToLaserScan.cpp) how can I detect how far a target is?